# Question from probability

Tags: probability

10 students appeared for two examinations. 6 students passed the first exam, 5 students passed the second exam, and 3 students passed both the first and the second exam.

What is the probability that a student selected at random has failed at least one of the two exams?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Have you, for example, tried to diagram the situation?

Comment: If we assume that the probabilities are uniformly distributed, then the answer will follow from an application of the inclusion-exclusion principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: Am I missing something there ?!
The probability of having failed at least one exam is $1-$ Pr[having passed both] $= 1-1/3$ ?

Comment: 1-3/10 but otherwise yes

Comment: Did you possibly mean to ask for the probability that a random student failed both exams?

Comment: @lulu I agree that this is a possibility. The original question was not worded clearly.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$The answer is as follows:

$\P$(the student failed at least one exam)=$1 - \P$(the student passed both exams)

It is given in the problem that $\P$(the student passed both exams)=$\frac{3}{10}$.

So the answer is $\frac{7}{10}$.

If what you meant to ask was:

"What is the probability that a student selected at random failed *both* exams?" then the answer is as follows:

$\P$(student failed both exams) = 1 - $\P$(student failed no exams)-$\P$(student failed exactly one exam)

We know from the question along with inclusion-exclusion that 3 students passed the first exam but not the second, and 2 students passed the second exam but not the second.

Therefore the answer is:

$1 - \frac{3}{10} - \frac{2+3}{10}= \frac{1}{5}$

More directly (to see the connection with inclusion-exclusion)

The number of people who passed at least one exam = number who passed the first + number who passed the second - number who passed both = 6+5-3 = 8, as was claimed above.